# Iterate through a Map with duplicate values and identify keys that share these values

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I have a `Map` of type `<String, Set<Object>>` that contains names and coordinates (`Double = X,Y`). These values are used to create graphs. The problem I encountered is that some points share the same coordinates and thus, they are barely visible as they appear one on top of the other. To deal with this issue I thought to iterate into the `Set` and increment by `0.01` only the `X` points.

While this fixes significantly the problem, it is not a perfect solution as some points still collide with others.

Is there a way to search in a `Map` for specific ranges of values at a time, e.g. `0.1-0.2, 0.2-0.3, etc.` and identify what `keys` appear in these ranges? Then I assume I could increment the ones that share the same `X`s within a specific range. This will prevent adding `0.01` to all the `X`s of a `key` and only to the ones that require to.

My code:

```
double i=0.01;

for (Map.Entry<String, Set<Coordinates>> serie : nameToCoordinates.entrySet()) {
    List<Double> xData = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> yData = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Coordinates coord : serie.getValue()) {

        xData.add(coord.getX()+i);
        yData.add(coord.getY());

     }

     i=i+0.01;

     chart.addSeries(serie.getKey(), xData, yData);

}
```

Example of input:

```
Point1   [[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7]] 
Point2   [[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]        ,[0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7]]                     
Point3   [[0.1,0.1]                ,[0.6,0.7]]
```

Comment: You can get `values` [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) and then compare to each other, with the keys you can do the same if needed via [keySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--)
As far as I know,there is no common access as you asked

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the problem, e.g. why is your output always `0.1` in the x array if you're incrementing `i` by `0.01` for each series (assuming `Point1` is one of the series keys)? And how would you determine the size of those ranges? If they are fixed, what if there are too many coordinates in one series? Your code also doesn't match your description: you state the value of your map is a list but your code uses sets.

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand why incrementing the coordinates would help. If labels overlap a small increment wouldn't help much and larger increments would distort the graph, wouldn't they? Maybe it would be best to show us a picture of your problem.

Comment: Btw I am assuming coordinate should contain X and Y value, then to use two different arrays for data is not a good option, due the data integrity, you should to use some coordinate object (including field as X and Y value) - in theory you can't be sure the same position in X array will match logical data on the same position in Y array..

Comment: @Thomas the example of output is before I try to add the 0.01.

Comment: So it is an example of input.

Comment: @AndrianekenaMoise exactly, that's the word I should have used - I will edit it now.

Comment: @Thomas large increments would distort the graph indeed, that's why I have set the input points to appear in every 0.1 and the increase is at 0.01 which prevents from ruining the graph.

Comment: won't it be nicer to just change the color of the points on the graph instead? (e.g increase the color intensity of a certain % if that set of pixels is redrawn)

Comment: @nafas this could work if there were only few points colliding, but in my case you can have even more than five in the same coordinates. Thus, it is very hard to notice which color/shape of point appears.

Comment: @JohnStef yeah, but if u have more than 5 points colliding, u are just moving those points around. they are not the true values. btw,  not arguing about ur solution is right or wrong, I thought to give u another perspective that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that looks something like this. It'll give you back all keys that have an x or y coord between your min and max range. You just have to do something with the list of keys that it returns. Like increment the value that belongs to that key.
And ofcourse change the function slightly to fit the type of objects you are using :p. Good luck!

```
private List<String> getKeyRange(Map<String, List<Object> map, double min, double max){
    List<String> keys = new List<>();
    for(String key : map.getKeys()){
        Object coord = map.get(key);
        if( (coords.getX() > min && coords.getX() < max) || (coord.getX() > min && coord.getY() < max) ){
            keys.add(key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reg. these operations with Map you will need to implement it on your own, especially if you are using some custom object for it, refer bellow for instance, how you can have defined things:

Coordinate object (contains X and Y double value)

```
class CoordObj {
        double Xval;
        double Yval;

        public CoordObj(double xval, double yval) {
            Xval = xval;
            Yval = yval;
        }

        public double getXval() {
            return Xval;
        }

        public double getYval() {
            return Yval;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "coord: ["+Xval+"," + Yval +"]";
        }

    }
```

For testing purpose I created generator function to fill coordinates object

```
HashMap<Integer, CoordObj> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        CoordObj item = new CoordObj(generateDouble(), generateDouble());
        dataMap.put(i, item);
}

return dataMap;
```

And then filtering by X coordinates in range works as follows (can be pretty easily customized to filter per Y coordinate; similar part can be used for comparison of two coordinates members- with inner loop eg.):

```
public static void filterCoordsByX(Map<Integer,CoordObj> data,double min, double max) {

        ArrayList<Integer> foundKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, CoordObj> entryChecked : data.entrySet()){
                if(entryChecked.getValue().getXval() > min && entryChecked.getValue().getXval() < max ) {
                    foundKeys.add(entryChecked.getKey());
                }
        }

        System.out.println("for min: " + min + ", and max: " + max + " found keys:" + foundKeys.toString());
        System.out.println("backward check:");
        for (int i = 0; i < foundKeys.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("key: " + foundKeys.get(i) +", value: " + data.get(foundKeys.get(i)));
        }
    }
```

Output from testing

```
generated: 3.61911823406948
generated: 4.970659057619206
generated: 0.19778377925564672
generated: 6.223897657222775
generated: 9.86588783431928
generated: 4.211157245481315
generated: 2.4889283969102562
generated: 9.253484002587617
generated: 5.003925383598808
generated: 0.9279033924004261
for min: 2.0, and max: 4.0 found keys:[0, 3]
backward check:
key: 0, value: coord: [3.61911823406948,4.970659057619206]
key: 3, value: coord: [2.4889283969102562,9.253484002587617]
```

Comment: Will this work if a key has points outside of the specified range? Because I don't want these Xs to increase as well, only the ones within the range.

Comment: As you can see, this snippet is checking "X" coordinates only, and it was `generated in range from 0.92 till 9.8`, its `filtered from 2.0 until 4.0`